# React Native Expo Не могу сохранить pdf через Share после cборки и заливки в TestFlight

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, pdf, expo

Делал обновление своего IOS приложения и столкнулся с проблемой - через Expo GO все работает (функция генерации pdf printToFileAsync пакета expo-print и скачивание через Share из react-native) Но после создания билда и заливки в TestFlight функция перестает работать (Просто не открывается окно Sharing)
Сам по себе Sharing работает если убрать залитый в него uri, но как только я туда передаю либо url, либо base64 ссылку, на билде перестает работать(

Если передавать base64 напрямую в uri Share, тоже не работает

```js
let generatePdf = async() => {
  const file = await printToFileAsync({
    html: `
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Hello</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Hello</p>
        </body>
    </html>
          `,
    base64: true
  });

  let shareOptionsUrl = {
    url: `data:application/pdf;base64,${file.base64}`
  };

  await Share.share(shareOptionsUrl);

};
```

Функция создания и сохранения Pdf в моем приложении IOS
Заранее спасибо за помощь :3